# How do I run the bitcoin bx tool in my terminal

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I am reading the book Mastering Bitcoin. At some point, I came accross the `bx` command and tried to run it in the same way as `bitcoin-cli` (I've got a bitcoin core node running). But I just get the `command not found` message. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bx is found here: [libbitcoin-explorer](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer). There are copious notes there about how to install.

Can I also recommend noting [btcdeb](https://github.com/kallewoof/btcdeb) for assisting in debugging bitcoin script, should you get that deep.